# When can colourimetry be used to determine the rate of reaction?

Tags: redox, color

Can colourimetry be used if a coloured reactant react to give a coloured product? For example, in the reaction of reacting dichromate ions with oxalate ions in acidic environment, where dichormate ions (orange) react to give chromium three ions (green)?

Comment: It can be used if reaction is slow enough.

Comment: In a more general sense, spectroscopy is used nowadays to measure reactions on all time scales from tens of femtoseconds ($10^{-15}$ s)  to hours. If a laser can be used to start the reaction these methods are now called 'pump-probe' but used to be called 'flash photolysis'. Rapidly mixing reactants that then react without using a laser to initiate it,  which is the most general case,  and using spectroscopy to monitor the colour change is called 'stopped flow' .